# Spring boot application whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm getting whitelabel error page 404 with my springboot application. I am hardcoding a list of students and they should pop as firstname basis to the page. I've tried different approaches with the template but nothing seems to work. I also tried to do /* endpoint but didn't have any effect aswell. I couldn't find any relevant questions for this problem that would fix my problems. These are the different classes;

Controller;

```
public class StudentController {

private List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

@GetMapping("/hello")
public String friendListing(Model model) {
    Student student1 = new Student("Kate", "Cole");
    studentList.add(student1);
    Student student2 = new Student("Dan", "Brown");
    studentList.add(student2);
    Student student3 = new Student("Mike", "Mars");
    studentList.add(student3);
    model.addAttribute("studentList", studentList);
    return "hello";
}}
```

Model;

```
public class Student {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Student(String fn, String ln) {
    this.firstName = fn;
    this.lastName = ln;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}}
```

And view;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Server Programming with Spring Boot</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <tr th:each="student: ${studentList}">
        <td  th:text="${student.firstName}"></td>
        </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please share the configuration also.

Comment: make class as @RestController and try.. also share the which URL are you trying and what error you see in logs. Share configuration will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your main application class?

- Use `@ComponentScan` annotation with you controller class package
- Controller class should have `@Controller` annotation.

Comment: I am an idiot apparently. Forgot the controller annotation completely. It fixed my problem thanks! :)